# I want an HTML anchor call a page method and JUST that method;No page_load. Is that posiible?if it is then HOW?

Tags: asp.net, anchor, pageload

```
<a href="A.aspx?qs=2"></a>
```

clicking this should fire a method GetMeData(obj sender, eventargs e) in CodeBehind of  A.aspx
GetMeData() is also bound to an aspButton Ineed to reuse this method on a click event within
the HTML  link.

```
public void Page_Init(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["curPage"]))
        {
            FilterOrdersByDate();
        }
    }


public  void FilterOrdersByDate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { //with some bll logic it calls:
  List<ESalesOrder> list = bsales.GetSalesOrderAdminByDate(esalesDate,curPage,perPage);
}
```

But the call on FilterOrdersByDate(); never reaches to it nevertheless satisfies above condition...Instead it goes through the page load and execute whatever finds in page_load and done..there it is all.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it direclty, but something like this my do the trick

On `A.aspx.cs` you should have a code like this

```
protected void Page_Load(obj sender, eventargs e)
{
    // If querystring contains qs=2, I call CommonGetMeData method
    if (Request.QueryString["qs"] != null && Request.QueryString["qs"] == "2")
    {
        CommonGetMeData();
    }
    else
    {
        // here goes the rest of the page_load logic
    }       
}

protected void GetMeData(obj sender, eventargs e)
{
    // When event triggered, I also call CommonGetMeData method
    CommonGetMeData();
}

protected void CommonGetMeData()
{
    // your logic. This method will be called from event 
    // handler and in case querystring contains qs=2
}
```

Comment: > That is I cannot avoid executing the rest of the page load codes? Did u stucked just like me? Any way I will try this and let you know..

Comment: You could execute the rest of the page_load on `else`. Updated my answer.

Comment: >I tried that today though much not like you did by calling a method then call the target in it and again write it.. But mine did not work it just found it and ignored it as I saw through debug pointrt...

Answer (score 0):

Well... passing the query string isn't an issue at all.

Question: Where are you binding this data?

If you don't want to invoke the method on page_load you should invoke on_item_data_bound on the web control I suppose.

Method would look like this:

```
protected void On_ItemDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    //Request query string and do something.
}
```

Then you call this method on the web control.

Cheers.

Comment: > this "qs=2" data is bound to the method GetMeData ,which uses it by capturing fromReq.QryStrng["qs"], in turn brings me a query list from database...